# Horizontal slide down menu trouble alining elements horizontally

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slidedown

I have a vertical accordion menu that I want to translate into horizontal format. The reason for this is the structure and how all the sub elements aline perfectly below their parents. 
The ultimate goal is to have a slide down menu that slide down all sub elements and they stay alined under their parent elements.

The problem is I cannot get the top level `li` elements to `display:inline-block;`. They sit on top of each other and general make a mess. Is this becuase of the html structure?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcR8U/)

And an [example](http://www.kcl.ac.uk/index.aspx) of the kind of thing I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: Rookie mistake :( Thanks that works. But now the top level elements fall down with the sublevel ones. Any idea on a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now: http://jsfiddle.net/KcR8U/3/

I just updated the CSS like this:

```
#nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#nav li ul{
    /* other styles */
    position:absolute; 
    z-index: 100;     
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is really good. But now it fails to push the content down, even without the z-index.

Comment: @AdamBrown - ok, did you want something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KcR8U/4/?

Comment: hey thats pretty amazing! I want to get all the sub elements showing at once though. Hence why I was trying to aline them under each parent. I still cant work it out